Comparative vs Superlative adjectives (when in a group)
Im reading and studying up on comparative vs superlative adjectives.
I know that you use comparative adjectives when comparing only two things and you use superlative adjectives for comparing three or more things. Where I get confused is when you come across a group of things.
I came across this info on a website:

Although we use comparative adjectives when talking about two things (not three or more), one or both of the things may be a group of things. “Mt Everest is higher than all other mountains.” — Here, we are talking about hundreds of mountains, but we are still comparing one thing (Mt Everest) to one other thing (all other mountains).

— does this mean you cannot use the superlative "Mt Everest is the highest of all mountains"  ? as this surely is also comparing two things (Mt Everest and all mountains)
Could someone please clarify this for me? thanks

Both are correct. Higher than compares two sets (either of which can have a single or multiple elements). Highest of all compares every item in a set individually.

The quote isn't saying you can't use the superlative, it's just showing another way to use a comparative. Both are equivalent.

It's two things where one of the things is a group of things: all other mountains. Mt. Everest vs. all other mountains [as a group]. See?

@PeterKirkpatrick thanks Peter. "Highest of all..." — "compares every item in a set individually" — if i was to put "highest mountain of all..." or "highest mountain" would it still be doing the same thing? Also if I put "highest of all other mountains" the "other" would make that sentence seem incorrect, yes?

No, that's fine (if it's what you want to say.) You can qualify sets any way you like. John was the overall race winner. Cheryl was the fastest of the women, and Mark was the fastest in the junior division.

Transformation of sentences - Superlative, Comparative and Positive.
The book is explaining how to transform superlatives into other degrees,  without changing the meaning.
There are three types:
I. Absolute superlative (the best).
II. Relative superlatives (one of the best.).
III. Negative Superlatives (Not the best).
Your example comes under Absolute Superlative .
I. Absolute superlative.
Superlative:  Mt Everest is the highest mountain peak in the world.
Comparative::Mt Everest is higher than all other mountains.
Positive: No other mountain peak in the world is as high as Mt. Everest.
II. Relative Superlatives.
Superlative:   Tennyson was one of the greatest English poets.
Comparative:  Tennyson was greater than most English poets.
Positive: Few English poets are as great as Tennyson.
III. Negative Superlatives.
Superlative:   Gold is not the most expensive metal on earth.
Comparative: Some metals are more expensive than Gold .
Positive: Gold is not as expensive as some other metals.

Interesting, thanks. There is no alternative to "type 1, 2, and 3" terminology-wise? i.e. no other names for these?

@RoostyBoy I have edited my answer.
